# Wordpress on Chrome for iOS 9 can't display responsive tables for mobile, td always has display: table-cell

Tags: ios, css, wordpress

On Chrome for iOS 9 (iPhone 5) I can't display responsive tables for mobile, it always sets display style attribute for td as { display: table-cell }. I want every td to be on separate line, to behave as a row - it already works fine like this on all browsers on desktop, even Chrome - when I stretch it so it is small on the monitor. It looks fine on chrome developer tools in all mobile modes. It looks fine on saucelabs mobile phone simulator too.

When I save this page (cache it), and try to see it on Chrome for iOS on iPhone, it displays properly - each td on its own line (looks as a separate row). I suspect it's the wordpress that does some tinkering, since cached version displays fine. I am banging my head for hours and hours on this with no success.

Things I tried to fix it (all tries have failed) so it displays responsively (style for td has display: block;) on my iPhone:
1. Added  at the beginning of file,
2. Added display: block; clear: both; inline at the html-element-tag-level,
3. I clear cache and add javascript for alerting the css("display") and it still outputs the table-cell,
4. Add the id-s for each of the td-s and add 'display: block' to these specific td-s through external CSS,
5. Add piece of javascript that will change all td's 'display' to be 'block' ($("td").css("display","block"); ) whenever a select field is changed - works on cached version but not on my live version,
6. I can do the same thing from 5. (see above) to change display to none, but not to block!

If I remember what else I tried, I will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be resolved on iOS9 new version. I can no longer replicate it on Firefox for iOS 9.2.1 nor Chrome for iOS 9.2.1.

Comment: I can still replicate it on iOS 7 though.